# Possible reason of different results if adding () in the mysql query

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

```
SELECT ddlcno,max(id) pq FROM `employee` group by ddlcno having count(ddlcno)>1
```

Running the above in mysql gives 25 rows. But when I run the same query within() i.e.

```
(SELECT ddlcno,max(id) pq FROM `employee` group by ddlcno having count(ddlcno)>1 )
```

It gives me 391 rows. Possible reason for the same?

[image]

Comment: Where are you running this? I'm not aware that a leading parenthesis is even valid SQL syntax

Comment: in work bench you second query gives an error please show a working example https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Does it actually show any rows? It might help to provide a sample to look for differences.